# XTemplate and DataView displaying nothing

Tags: extjs

I need your help with my DataView and a XTemplate. No matter what I am trying, I am stuck in this problem, that the DataView is displaying nothing...
The json data seems ok to me and it is coming from the Spring MVC server side.
Here is an example of the retrieved data:

```
[
  {
    "id":58987552,
    "objectId":47841258,
    "type":"T1",
    "category":"FILE",
    "fileName":"file_9858585555_1",
    "extension":"pdf",
    "size":14397354,
    "version":34,
    "deleted":0,
    "locked":0},...
  }
]
```

For me it is looking like valid JSON data. Right?
This is my Extjs code:

```
Ext.require(['*']);

Ext.onReady(function(){
createStores();

var dataView = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('store'),
    tpl: [
      '<tpl for=".">',
        '<tpl switch="extension">',
            '<tpl case="pdf" case="PDF">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/pdf32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="xlsx" case="xls">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/xlsx32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="ppt" case="pptx">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/pptx32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="zip" case="7z">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/zip32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="msg">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/clarity/resources/images/32/msg32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="rtf" case="doc" case="docx">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/docx32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
        '</tpl>',
     '</tpl>'
    ],
    multiSelect: false,
    height: 400,
    trackOver: true,
    overItemCls: 'x-item-over',
    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
    emptyText: 'No images available',
});

Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        id: 'fileBrowser',
        frame: true,
        collapsible: true,
        width: 535,
        items: dataView,
        renderTo: 'documentViewPanel'
});
});
```

My stroe code:

```
var documentStore = null;

function createDocumentStores() {
var documentProxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    type : 'ajax',
    url : applicationPath + '/documentViewer/getWorkorders',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        idProperty : 'id'
    }
});

documentStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model : 'DocumentModel',
    storeId : 'documentStore',
    proxy : documentProxy,
    autoLoad : true
});
}
```

I am not sure what's wrong with the code, but the data isn't displayed in the DataView.
In my oppinion the for loop in the tpl wasn't entered. But I am not sure why.
Please help me, I am at my wit'sa end and I am desperating on this XTemplat mechanism.
Every help is very appriciated.

Best regards and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me, here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/x_window/25vaX/

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

var dataView = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    data: [{
        "id":58987552,
        "objectId":47841258,
        "type":"T1",
        "category":"FILE",
        "fileName":"file_9858585555_1",
        "extension":"pdf",
        "size":14397354,
        "version":34,
        "deleted":0,
        "locked":0
      },{
        "id":58987552,
        "objectId":47841258,
        "type":"T1",
        "category":"FILE",
        "fileName":"file_9858585555_1",
        "extension":"zip",
        "size":14397354,
        "version":34,
        "deleted":0,
        "locked":0
      }
    ],
    tpl: [
      '<tpl for=".">',
        '<tpl switch="extension">',
            '<tpl case="pdf" case="PDF">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/hu-HU/How-to/wp8/inline/basic-icon-pin.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="xlsx" case="xls">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/clarity/resources/images/32/xlsx32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="ppt" case="pptx">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/clarity/resources/images/32/pptx32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="zip" case="7z">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/hu-HU/How-to/wp8/inline/basic-icon-back.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="msg">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/clarity/resources/images/32/msg32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
            '<tpl case="rtf" case="doc" case="docx">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/clarity/resources/images/32/docx32.png"/></div>',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{fileName}.{extension}">',
                '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
        '</tpl>',
     '</tpl>'
    ],
    multiSelect: false,
    height: 400,
    trackOver: true,
    overItemCls: 'x-item-over',
    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
    emptyText: 'No images available',
});

Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        id: 'fileBrowser',
        frame: true,
        collapsible: true,
        width: 535,
        items: dataView,
        renderTo: document.body
});
});
```

Check that there are items in your store or not.

Comment: No I think there is something with the store going wrong or with the data of the store... because you changed the store config in your data... and it is working. I added the code of my store in my previous qustion. Maybe you find a failure there. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: By the way the store contains a lot of data. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed my view code to:

```
tpl: [
      '<tpl for=".">',
        '<tpl switch="suffix">',
            '<tpl case="pdf" case="PDF">',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/pdf32.png" title="{fileName}.{suffix}"/></div>',
                '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span></div>',
            '<tpl case="xlsx" case="xls">',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/clarity/resources/images/32/xlsx32.png" title="{fileName}.{suffix}"/></div>',
                '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span></div>',
            '<tpl case="ppt" case="pptx">',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/pptx32.png" title="{fileName}.{suffix}"/></div>',
                '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span></div>',
            '<tpl case="zip" case="7z">',
            '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/zip32.png" title="{fileName}.{suffix}"/></div>',
                '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span></div>',
            '<tpl case="msg">',
                '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/msg32.png" title="{fileName}.{suffix}"/></div>',
                '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span></div>',
            '<tpl case="rtf" case="doc" case="docx">',
            '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">',
                '<div class="thumb"><img src="/site/resources/images/32/docx32.png" title="{fileName}.{suffix}"/></div>',
                '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span></div>',
        '</tpl>',
     '</tpl>',
     '<div class="x-clear"></div>'
    ],
```

And now it is realy working. 
If you want the look and feel of this example: 
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/view/data-view.html
Don't forget to copy the CSS file: data-view.css.
Thank you very much fpór your help.